# How to make boost threads self-destruct? (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, function, boost

I have a class with some function like:

```
void workerFunc(int ClassVariable)  
{  
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(classVariableA);  

    std::cout << "Worker: running" << std::endl;  

    // Pretend to do something useful...  
    boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);  


    std::cout << ClassVariable << std::endl;  
    std::cout << "Worker: finished" << std::endl;  
}
```

which I want to be in threads. and some other function that I want to work like

```
while(1)
{
 boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc(ClassVariableB));  
}
```

so it will create thread each time it can. But what I need is for that thread to auto destruct itself when it is finished.  How to do such thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to do anything for that. You just have to make sure that the thread really finishes (i.e. no infinite loops or such).

Comment: Ok - I love how that sounds. But if that is true what is thread.join used for?

Comment: Sometimes you have threads that have infinite loops (e.g. listening for incoming network traffic). In that case, you would have to send a signal to that thread to make it stop, and then join with it to make sure it really stopped. Another scenario is when a thread is doing some task for you, and you can only continue when that task is finished.

Answer (score 2):

A thread will automatically end when it finishes running the function for which it was created.

join is a strange word, it really means wait_for which means wait for the thread to finish executing.

If you want to retain a thread for re-use, it is normally implemented by making its function loop, each time reaching a "wait" state, where it gets alerted (woken up) when something it is waiting for happens. At some point this will be a termination request, or a request that leads to its termination.